# Compare two lists based on a condition - C#

Tags: c#, list

I have two separate  lists of `<double>` type as:

```
 Index List1  List2

   0  1000   -500

   1  900    -200

   2  600    100

   3  400    250

   4  200    400

   5  100    500

   6  50     1500
```

I want to get index number when value in List2>List1 ***for the first time***, i.e. in the above example that would be index = 4 as 400>200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int position;
for(int i = 0; i < List2.Count; ++i)
{
    if(List2[i] > List1[i]) // or Math.Abs(List2[i]-List1[i]) > epsilon
    {
        position = i; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming both lists have the same count...otherwise `int maxCount = Math.Min(List1.Count, List2.Count);` and `for(int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)`

Comment: Thanks.. Is there anyway to use Linq statement if FOR loop is not desired.

Comment: If you want to avoid a for loop, check out my alternative answer. A for loop is perfectly fine though.

Comment: If you put ++i in the loop you will never compare the first position

Comment: @FernandoOrtu, the operation, after condition expression in for statement, will be executed after for' body. So, you don't right, it will compare the first items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Zip` (to combine the lists) and `TakeWhile` (to iterate until a condition is / isn't met) to achieve this. This code also works fine if listA and listB aren't the same size.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var listA = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var listB = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 };

            var combined = listA.Zip(listB, (first, second) => new { first, second })
                .TakeWhile(z => z.first >= z.second); ;
            var countWhereListIsGreater = combined.Count();

            var index = (countWhereListIsGreater >= listA.Count || 
                countWhereListIsGreater >= listB.Count)
                ? -1
                : countWhereListIsGreater;

            Console.WriteLine(index);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are sure the two lists are the same size, then this would also work:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            var listA = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var listB = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 };

            var result = listA.Select((currentValue, index)
                => new { currentValue, index })
                .Where(z => listB[z.index] > z.currentValue)
                .Select(z => (int?)z.index).FirstOrDefault() ?? -1;

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 static int Position(List<double> list1, List<double> list2) 
 for(int i =0; i < list1.Count; i++) 
 {
 if(list2[i] > list1[i]) return i;
 } 
 return -1;
```

If the position that return is -1 means that in the second list there isn't any number > than in the first list. You call it like that

```
 int position = Position(List1, List2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.IndexOf(list1.Where((currentValue, index) => list2[index] > currentValue).FirstOrDefault());
```

**Side note:** list2 Size >= list1 Size. Or check it before